# Take focus on next input after key up using Jquery

Tags: jquery, focus, onkeyup

Note: My page has just textboxes. Nothing else. (nothing else => no other input types)

```
 $(":input[type='text']").keyup(function(event){

   if(valid)
     {
         // take a focus to next input element, which is again a text type.
     }

  });
```

How can i jump the focus to next input element after key up.

After Sarfraz Answer:-

```
 <div>
   <input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" >
   <input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" > 
   <input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" > // sarfraj -- here it crash   Please check below for error.
 </div>


 <div>
   <input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" >
   <input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" >
   <input type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" >
 </div>
```

From firebug issue is

```
  $(this).next("[type=\"text\"]")[0] is undefined
  [Break On This Error] $(this).next('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update:

Here is how you should modify your code:

```
$(":input[type='text']").keyup(function(event){
   if(valid) {
      if ($(this).next('[type="text"]').length > 0){
         $(this).next('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
      }
      else{
         if ($(this).parent().next().find('[type="text"]').length > 0){
            $(this).parent().next().find('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
         }
         else {
           alert('no more text input found !');
         }
      }

   }
});
```

---

> How can i jump the focus to next input element after key up.

Use the `next()` with `focus`:

```
$(this).next('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
```

So here is how your code should look like:

```
$(":input[type='text']").keyup(function(event){
   if(valid) {
      $(this).next('[type="text"]')[0].focus();
   }
});
```

Comment: Hey dude.. I was using the same code. But it crash if the input element is last in that div. Lemme edit my question for better explanation..

Comment: The trouble is that `next()` iterates over siblings, once you run out of siblings you are done. Seeing your markup your options are. (a) iterate over all `input` elements till you find the next one (b) use my code (I haven't test it, but should work).

Comment: I don't mind this answer, however it's shaky in that it's very specific to the layout of the site, if the structure changes (lets say you do a new theme or something) it'll break the code.

Comment: @Ali: I agree, assuming markup remains same here. Your answer is good to go for too.

Comment: Mohit has made his choice :-) I'm a software developer by nature and most of my front-end assignments require OOP style coding, so re-usability and decoupling of functionality from layout is very important. Even if you aren't required to do OOP style programming, you should decouple functionality from the presentation layer (it's just a good practice).

Comment: @Ali: Agreed, I do the same personally :)

Comment: I would simplify to:
var element = $(this).next('[type="text"]');
if (element) element[0].focus();
and so on

Answer (score 3):

The html [`tabindex`](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TABINDEX.html) property is used to define the order by which you move through the input elements if you hit tab. I would start by setting this.

So set the tab indexes then (to expand on your example):

```
 $(":input[type='text']").keyup(function(event){
   if(valid)
     {
         var currentIndex = $(this).attr("tabindex");
         var nextIndex = parseInt(currentIndex)+1;
         $("input[tabindex='"+nextIndex+"']").focus();
     }
  });
```

Basically get the `tabindex` of the current element, add 1, and get the element with that tab index.

Comment: You can use jQuery's `next()` directly rather than calculating tabindex :)

Comment: No doubt, but my thinking was different from yours. In that I assumed for whatever reason he may want a specific iteration order. Btw, as a fellow Pakistani (I know my profile says AU but I'm in KHI [moving soon]) I would appreciate an invite on careers if you have one.

Comment: @Ali: I am not sure there is an Invite option, i logged in and did not find any invite option.

Comment: @Sarfarz, no worries, they say it's either by invite of an other member or stackoverflow reviews your profiles. Apparently my stackoverflow score, github public projects and linkedIn aren't up to StackOverflow standards.

Comment: @Ali: Let me complete my profile and then see if I get the invite privilege.