# 4-digit form on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement four digit password form using bootstrap.

I am trying to do something similar to `iCloud` second `authentication` method.

I would like to center the content of the modal and autofocus on each text field. I've used `jQuery` Autotab but it doesnt work on `iOS`. My application is a mobile web app so working on `iOS` is a must.

What do you suggest? Is there anything already made that I can use and save time by the way?

```
<div id="digitPassword" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="digitPasswordlbl" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm vertical-align-center">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="digitPasswordlbl">Enter your four-digit password:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style=".row {text-align: center}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="formType" value="confirmPassword">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input name="firstdigit" id="firstdigit" class="digit" type="password" required id="firstdigit" size="1" maxlength="1">
                                    <input name="secondtdigit" class="digit" type="password" required id="firstdigit" size="1" maxlength="1">
                                    <input name="thirddigit" class="digit" type="password" required id="thirddigit" size="1" maxlength="1">
                                    <input name="fourthdigit" class="digit" type="password" required id="fourthdigit" size="1" maxlength="1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <!-- Do NOT use name="submit" or id="submit" for the Submit button -->

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default digit">Confirm</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#digitPasswordbtn').click(function() {
                $('#digitPassword').modal('show');
                $('.digit').autotab('nospace', 'filter', { format: 'number', target: '#firstdigit' });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To center the content you can use the `text-center` class, provided by the `Bootstrap`.

And to achieve the auto focus in the modal, you have to use the modal events and for transferring tab control to the next input you can use a small `jQuery` code referred from this post : [Take focus on next input after key up using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217360/take-focus-on-next-input-after-key-up-using-jquery).

Check out this fiddle : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/expxftpb/2/)

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, before you post I was reading some questions here, that iOS doesnt support autofocus, for security reasons and I was like "ooooh No". This is exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to auto focus on the first text field, when the modal show up? I would like when the modal show up to force the user to fill the 1st text field, to prevent any miss tapping on the next text fields.